# Why does slides[i].frame print a different value than SlideScrollView.subviews[i].frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I was trying to calculate the current visible "Slide" in my `UIScrollView` when I noticed this. I couldn't figure out why I am getting these values. Especially frame 2 & 3 show strange values.

can anyone tell me if and where I am wrong and how do I get the bottom values to match that of the top?

**Here is my code :**

```
{...}
for i in 0 ..< slides.count
        {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x:CONSTwid * CGFloat(i),y:0,width:CONSTwid+20,height : view.frame.height)
            print("slide \(i) frame : \(slides[i].frame)")
            SlideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
        let container = CGRect(x: SlideScrollView.contentOffset.x, y: SlideScrollView.contentOffset.y, width: SlideScrollView.frame.size.width, height: SlideScrollView.frame.size.height)

//this was just to see the result (do not ask me to loop it...I know :-P)

        print("sr \(container)")
        print("srcz\(SlideScrollView.contentSize)")
        print("slide 0 frame \(SlideScrollView.subviews[0].frame)")
        print("slide 1 frame \(SlideScrollView.subviews[1].frame)")
        print("slide 2 frame \(SlideScrollView.subviews[2].frame)")

{...}
```

here is the output :

**Console Output :**
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like SideScrollView already had a subview before you added your 3, so the indices are off by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure how a subview of that size got into my scrollview. guess I'll have to figure that out now.

Comment: You can assign tag values to view and then try to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `slides` is an array of views you wan't to check then that is the array you need to use. Although `subviews` is opened property it can still hold views you should not be looking into. Basically any view can have any number of subviews for any reason. This may even vary between devices or OS versions.

In your case you seem to have an extra view of size `2.5 x 7` that looks like a very small view. Perhaps a scroll indicator?